# For loop through string array with array.each do not working?

Tags: ruby, actionmailer, pony

I'm working on a basic contact form as part of learning Ruby where there are a string of email addresses in an array and the message in a contact form is sent to each one through Rails Pony.

```
ADDRESSES_BOOK = ['example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com']
def deliver
return false unless valid?
ADDRESSES_BOOK.each do |address|
  Pony.mail({
    :to => ADDRESSES_BOOK[address],
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),
    :reply_to => email,
    :subject => subject,
    :body => contactFormMessage,
  })
end
end
```

I'm doing something wrong with the loop, as it throws the error "no implicit conversion of String into Integer."

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ADDRESSES_BOOK.each do |address|
  Pony.mail({
    :to => address
    #...
  })
end
```

When you do `ADDRESSES_BOOK[address]` is like saying `ADDRESSES_BOOK['example1@example.com']` which is trying to access the value of the array at index 'example1@example.com', but array indexes are integers and start from 0.

So

```
ADDRESSES_BOOK[0] # returns 'example1@example.com'

ADDRESSES_BOOK[1] # returns 'example2@example.com'
```

The `.each` will iterate over each element in the array and put it `address`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.....
    :to => address,
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),
    :reply_to => email,
    :subject => subject,
    :body => contactFormMessage,
.....
```